# IOS 9 push notification custom sound arriving after message

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, ios9

I'm using Parse service for push notifications.
On two different phones:
Iphone 5s IOS9
Iphone 6 IOS8.4

On Iphone 6 the push notification and the custom sound arriving at the same time.

On Iphone 5 push notification arrives. and sound after a minutes or two .

Is any one else facing this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the code in the app delegate ?